# Validate <input type ="date">

Tags: javascript, html

How can I check the `<input type="date">` to verify if it exceeds today's date or not before submitting ?

The form will not submit if future date is in the input,

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <label>Member Since </label>
                <input id="since" name="since" size="2" maxlength="6" value="" type="date" required />
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="Submit" name="Submit" id="btnsubmit" value="Submit" onclick="checkDate();" />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In your checkDate function, retrieve the value from the input field.  Then create a new Date() object set to the day you want to make sure the input is not exceeding.  From there, you can do a simple comparison between the two dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try converting the input value to a [Date Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) to compare today and the input value in your script.

```
input = document.getElementById("since"); // gets element
value = input.value; // form value (string)
date = new Date(value); // converts string to date object
now = new Date(); // current date
if (now > date) {
    // in past
} else {
    // in future
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check two things.
 1) was a valid date entered, 
2) is the date in the range you want it.
 try the code bellow, it will check for both conditions before allowing a submit.

```
    <html>   
    <head></head>    
    <body>      
    <script>
    function checkDate() {
     var val = new Date(document.forms["frm"]["since"].value);
     var now = new Date();
     if (isNaN(val.getTime()) || (val>now)) {
       alert('invalid date');
       return false;
      }
      return true;
    }
    </script>
       <form name="frm" onsubmit="return checkDate()">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <label>Member Since </label>
        <input id = "since" name="since" size="2" maxlength="6" value="" type="date" required/>
       </li>
       <li>
         <input type="Submit" name="Submit" id="btnsubmit" value="Submit" />
        </li>
    </ul>
  </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like that should help you.

```
var dateText = document.getElementById('since').value;
var date = new Date(dateText);
var now = new Date();
if (date > now) {
  console.log("Date needs to be in the past");
}
```